# How can I stop vim from moving / deleting a file just before saving?

Tags: swap-file

When I save a file in vim, it does following operations:

```
$ inotifywait -r -m -c src/
src/,CREATE,4913
src/,OPEN,4913
src/,ATTRIB,4913
src/,"CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE",4913
src/,DELETE,4913
src/,MOVED_FROM,App.tsx
src/,MOVED_TO,App.tsx~
src/,MODIFY,.App.tsx.swp
<0.5 second pause, probably caused by the hard drive's seek time>
src/,CREATE,App.tsx
src/,OPEN,App.tsx
src/,MODIFY,App.tsx
src/,MODIFY,App.tsx
src/,MODIFY,App.tsx
src/,ATTRIB,App.tsx
src/,"CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE",App.tsx
src/,ATTRIB,App.tsx
src/,MODIFY,.App.tsx.swp
src/,DELETE,App.tsx~
```

During the pause in the middle, file-watching compilers often try to compile while the file doesn't exist! Is there a way to make vim copy the file instead of moving it? Or is there another way to solve the problem?

(note, it looks like vim does copy backups automatically in some directories but not others)

Comment: See `:help 'backupcopy'`, together with related options (`'backup'`, `'writebackup'`), I'm not sure which exact combination of options you need but check them to see if you find the one that works right for your use case...

Comment: Thanks! `set backupcopy=yes` maked it do it in all directories, solving the issue.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

This works: `:set backupcopy=yes`